# IE 11 not supporting audio playing?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I have checked w3schools.com and createElement(), setAttribute() and play() are all meant to be supported by IE 11? The below JS code works fine in other modern browsers. Thoughts?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var amusic = document.createElement('audio');
   amusic.setAttribute('src', 'sing.wav');
   amusic.play();
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Live example - https://jsfiddle.net/40x303ka/

Comment: Are you hosting this on a server or your local filesystem?

Comment: @code4coffe I am using XAMPP via localhost, I have tried entering the full URL without success and also using ngrok to see if that changes anything but that does not help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code specifies a WAV file as the audio file. As seen on the [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp), Internet Explorer does not support WAV files.

For maximum cross-browser support, I would reccomend either using an MP3 file, or even better, specifying files based on browser compatibility like so:

```
var amusic = document.createElement('audio');
var source= document.createElement('source');
if (audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;')) {
    source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
    source.src= 'audio/sing.mp3';
} else {
    source.type= 'audio/ogg';
    source.src= 'audio/sing.ogg';
}
amusic.appendChild(source);
```

If you still want to use a WAV file, check out this link:
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play5.htm

It uses the non-standard bgsound tag that is used only by IE to play WAV files.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a windows server and I had the same problem playing MP3 audios in internet explorer.

The only solution I found was installing the "Desktop Experience Feature" in my server.

> Start -> Search for "Server manager" -> Features -> Add features -> Select "Desktop experience" -> Next and Install

Once installation is completed, you need to restart the computer and then the feature gets enabled.